# Xamarin Forms implementing TK.CustomMaps

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

This is probably a very simple fix, but I can't seem to find a full example of the implementation of TK.Custom maps in a Xamarin Forms project anywhere. As far as I can tell the below code should work as expected, however when debugging using the Universal Windows element of the project I can't see the custom Pin, even removing the imagesource (which according to the documentation should revert the pin image to the default) doesn't resolve the issue.

It's also worth noting that the map, pin, and drag events don't fire. At least they don't appear to when debugging the UWP app.

**XAML:**

```
<ContentPage.Content>
<Grid VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="Fill">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Entry x:Name="Searchbar" Text="Town, City, Postcode ..." TextColor="Gray" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" />
    <z:TKCustomMap x:Name="mapView" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" IsVisible="False" />
    <maps:Map x:Name="mapViewNative"  Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" MapType="Hybrid" IsVisible="False"/>
  <Button x:Name="nextBtn"  Grid.Row="2" Clicked="NextClicked" Text="Next" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="End"/>
</Grid>
```

**C#** [SetPosition() is fired on page initialisation]

```
    Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.Position location = null;
    private ObservableCollection<TKCustomMapPin> _pins = new ObservableCollection<TKCustomMapPin>();

    private async void SetPosition()
    {
        mapView.IsVisible = true;

        if (CrossGeolocator.Current.IsGeolocationAvailable)
        {
            location = await CrossGeolocator.Current.GetPositionAsync();

            mapView.SetBinding(TKCustomMap.CustomPinsProperty, "Pins");
            mapView.SetBinding(TKCustomMap.MapClickedCommandProperty, "MapClickedCommand");
            mapView.SetBinding(TKCustomMap.MapLongPressCommandProperty, "MapLongPressCommand");
            mapView.SetBinding(TKCustomMap.MapCenterProperty, "MapCenter");
            mapView.SetBinding(TKCustomMap.PinSelectedCommandProperty, "PinSelectedCommand");
            mapView.SetBinding(TKCustomMap.SelectedPinProperty, "SelectedPin");
            mapView.SetBinding(TKCustomMap.RoutesProperty, "Routes");
            mapView.SetBinding(TKCustomMap.PinDragEndCommandProperty, "DragEndCommand");
            mapView.SetBinding(TKCustomMap.CirclesProperty, "Circles");
            mapView.SetBinding(TKCustomMap.CalloutClickedCommandProperty, "CalloutClickedCommand");
            mapView.SetBinding(TKCustomMap.PolylinesProperty, "Lines");
            mapView.SetBinding(TKCustomMap.PolygonsProperty, "Polygons");
            mapView.SetBinding(TKCustomMap.MapRegionProperty, "MapRegion");
            mapView.SetBinding(TKCustomMap.RouteClickedCommandProperty, "RouteClickedCommand");
            mapView.SetBinding(TKCustomMap.RouteCalculationFinishedCommandProperty, "RouteCalculationFinishedCommand");
            mapView.SetBinding(TKCustomMap.TilesUrlOptionsProperty, "TilesUrlOptions");
            mapView.SetBinding(TKCustomMap.MapFunctionsProperty, "MapFunctions");

            mapView.IsRegionChangeAnimated = true;

            mapView.PinSelected += pinClicked;
            mapView.MapClicked += mapClicked;
            mapView.PinDragEnd += pinDragEnd;

            //mapView.IsShowingUser = true;

            mapView.CustomPins = _pins;

            var initPin = new TKCustomMapPin()
            {
                IsDraggable = true,
                Position = new Position(location.Latitude, location.Longitude),
                IsVisible = true,
                Title = "Concern Location",
                Image = Device.OnPlatform("pinicon.png", "pinicon.png", "Assets/pinicon.png")
            };

            this._pins.Remove(initPin);
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            this._pins.Add(initPin);

            mapView.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(initPin.Position.Latitude, initPin.Position.Longitude), Distance.FromMiles(0.3)));
        }
    }
```

'Initpin' gets the location properly and the map movesregion to the correct position, but just doesn't want to display the custom pin. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hello, I want to integrate TKCustom Map in my xamarin app but didn't find the working code. I follow the instruction and try to make the demo but the map doesn't display on iOS 11. If you have working code for it, can you help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone that gets here looking for a solution, it turns out that using an IObservableCollection to pass the custom pins to the TKCustomMap was the cause of the issue. I used a standard TKCustomPin[] array and it worked perfectly. Since I posted this message, I've since stopped using the TKCustomMap plugin, and instead merged the work into our code base and carried on implementing missing features, improving the code where required etc. Highly recommend others doing the same, it's a solid base, but hasn't seen much development in recent months.

Comment: Any reason why you are not contributing and doing PR's to the code base?

Comment: No special reason really but I guess mainly that my experience with the code base has been limited to adaptation for work purposes. Any particular reason why you ask? =)

Comment: Well... let me indeed ask it in a different way ;) are your improvements public available? Or anything available you can share? :)

Comment: haha well no not currently, I'm not entirely sure that changes I make a work are mine to share in all honesty. also there's still quite a lot of work to do to the UWP version, currently our build of that is a bit broken because of the way touch is propagated in UWP applications. That said from the looks of Torbens GitHub the original has seen some more work lately, and a new update to 2.0.1 that looks to be fairly solid at the moment.

Comment: Yeah, my test app works with all functionality I need :)

Comment: @JoeTomks I know is a couple of years later. by any chance, could you share a snippet of your fix? I just can't get that pin to show on the map. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to reproduce your code.

This is my xaml

```
 xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Maps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Maps"
 xmlns:customMap="clr-namespace:TK.CustomMap;assembly=TK.CustomMap"
```

however, I don't know how to integrate the drop and drag pin functionality.

Comment: In the end, we recreated TKMaps approach to this solution and fixed some of the things that had not been considered. The drop and drag functionality was only working on android when we last used it. Are you using this in a forms project?

Comment: yes , I am using in it on the portable class and this is the only issue I have so far mapView.PinSelected += pinClicked;
    mapView.MapClicked += mapClicked;
    mapView.PinDragEnd += pinDragEnd; ....... I think I am missing the method of the mapClicked , pinDragEnd

Comment: Thank you for reply by the way . very kind

Comment: its not a problem, just trying to remember back to when we did this stuff ourselves. It could be that your binding doesn't match up correctly with the command. So for us to use pindragend we had to do the following:

mapView.SetBinding(ExtendedMap.PinDragEndCommandProperty, "DragEndCommand");

Then use 

mapView.PinDragEnd -= pinDragEnd;
mapView.PinDragEnd += pinDragEnd;

Comment: Thank you for reply ! very nice of you

Comment: Geocoder geoCoder;


        public ProblemView()
        {


            InitializeComponent();
            Locator();
            geoCoder = new Geocoder();
         
            var pin = new CustomPin
            {
                Pin = new Pin
                {
                    Type = PinType.Place,
                    Position = new Position(37.79752, -122.40183),
                    Label = "Xamarin San Francisco Office",
                    Address = "394 Pacific Ave, San Francisco CA"
                },

Comment: how can change it to my the user current location ? thanks